# Rails: On-the-fly Destroy cascade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cascade, destroy, on-the-fly

I know that `destroy cascade` will work if proper relationships are setup in the models, but I want to know whether there is a way to `destroy cascade` on-the-fly, without needing to have everything setup? Maybe something like `model.destroy :cascade`?

Or am I limited to raw SQL in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of way of doing it on the fly, but rather than using raw SQL try this:

```
AssociatedModel.destroy_all(:model_id => @model.id)
@model.destroy
```